# How to process each iteration of list of items in rxjava with retrofit in Android

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java, reactive-programming

I am a newbie in RxJava programming and I want to ask about how to process each iteration of list that I have from a retrofit call. Basically what I want to do is:

1. Get list of appointments
2. Iterate each appointment and get the patient_id and the subservice_id
3. Convert back to list of appointments

Here is my code so far

```
Observable<List<Appointment>> callAppointments = appointmentServiceRx.getService().getConfirmedAppointments(user_id);
    callAppointments.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .flatMapIterable(apps -> apps)
            .concatMap(app -> getPatientById(app)
                    .doOnNext(this::addPatientNames)
                    .map(patient -> app)
            ).concatMap(app -> getSubserviceById(app)
                    .doOnNext(this::addSubserviceNames)
                    .map(subservice -> app)
            ).toList()
            .subscribe(res -> doStuff(),
                    throwable -> showThrowable());
```

Please help and thank you in advance...

Comment: What does your code do? How does it fall short?

Comment: @MatthewCliatt basically I want to retrieve a list of appointments by using callAppointments observable, then I want to retrieve each item in the list and get the patient_id, get the patient of the patient_id, and save the patient name by using addPatientNames. Then I want to convert it back to appointment observable to get the subservice this time (with the same actions as the patient). Finally I want to get back the list of appointments. It throws and I am not sure where I do wrong.

Comment: Yes, but **what** does it throw? Assuming that `getPatientById()` and `getSubserviceById()` are also network calls you'll maybe need another `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` just above the `subscribe()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` call right at the beginning forces all subsequent operators to run on the main thread, which then throws `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Try moving this call to the last point before the `subscribe`:

```
// ...
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(res -> doStuff(),
    throwable -> showThrowable());
```